# Convert sound in Core Audio (iOS): 1 buffer 2 channels to 2 buffers and each has 1 channel?

Tags: ios, buffer, core-audio, channel

I used OrigamiEngine to play flac files. But the problem is I need to convert its output data (it used standard Core Audio with a custom static function) in [this file](https://github.com/ap4y/OrigamiEngine/blob/0bbdc3c5344b631e039a67a0aff481746e1aded3/OrigamiEngine/ORGMOutputUnit.m).

Code:

```
static OSStatus Sound_Renderer(void *inRefCon,
                               AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                               const AudioTimeStamp  *inTimeStamp,
                               UInt32 inBusNumber,
                               UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                               AudioBufferList  *ioData) {
    ORGMOutputUnit *output = (ORGMOutputUnit *)inRefCon;
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    void *readPointer = ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;

    int amountToRead, amountRead;

    amountToRead = inNumberFrames * (output->_format.mBytesPerPacket);
    amountRead = [output readData:(readPointer) amount:amountToRead];

    if (amountRead < amountToRead) {
        int amountRead2;
        amountRead2 = [output readData:(readPointer+amountRead) amount:amountToRead-amountRead];
        amountRead += amountRead2;
    }

    ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = amountRead;
    ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = output->_format.mChannelsPerFrame;
    ioData->mNumberBuffers = 1;

    return err;
}
```

So `ioData` has 1 buffer and 2 channels but I need vice versa - 2 buffers when each of them contains 1 channel. Or simply:

`LRLRLR...` -> `LLL...` + `RRR...`

**UPDATED**

In general I need to achieve something like the following:

```
ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = ...;
ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
ioData->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize = ...;
ioData->mBuffers[1].mNumberChannels = 1;
ioData->mNumberBuffers = 2;
```

Comment: It sound like you want have interleaved stereo and you want split stereo.  Correct?

    deviceFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;

Comment: it seems to be incorrect because the audio is played via one speaker only